# Merging two datasets by the values of three columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of about 500,000 animals `IndivID` of various species `binSpecies`.

```
Dataset <- data.frame(
  IndivID <- (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
  binSpecies <- ("Dog", "Gato", "Canine", "Chienne", "Jument", "Avian", "Caballo", "Dog", "Cat", "Gato")
)
```

Some of the species names in my dataset are outdated or incorrect and I have cross referenced them with an official source `IOCSpecies`, creating a dataset `Names` which connects every `binSpecies` name to its `IOCSpecies` name.

```
Names <- data.frame(
  IOCSpecies <- c( "Canine", "Feline", "Equine", "Avian"),
  binSpecies1 <- c("Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Bird"),
  binSpecies2 <- c("Perro", "Gato", "Caballo", "Pajaro"),
  binSpecies3 <- c("Chienne", "Chatte", "Jument",  "Oiseau")
)
```

I am trying to find a way to add the `IOCSpecies` to my main dataset based on the `binSpecies` so that I can eventually ‘group_by’ `IOCSpecies`.

A final dataset could look like

```
Output <- data.frame(
  IndivID <- (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  binSpecies <- ("Dog", "Gato", "Canine", "Chienne", "Jument", "Avian", "Caballo", "Dog", "Cat", "Gato"),
  IOCSpecies <- ("Canine," "Feline", "Canine", "Canine", "Equine", "Avian", "Equine", "Canine", "Feline", "Feline)
```

or like

```
IndivID <- (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
IOCSpecies <- ("Canine," "Feline", "Canine", "Canine", "Equine", "Avian", "Equine", "Canine", "Feline", "Feline)
```

I have tried `merge` but cannot get it to work due to there being three binSpecies columns. Essentially I want my code to add a column where if "Dog," "Perro", or "Chienne" input "Canine," however I need it to do this automatically as I have >1500 IOCSpecies.
I’m totally at a loss and don’t know even know what keywords to google.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First make a long list of all your name pairs. I added the correct names too, otherwise those aren't matched. Then we can do a simple join.

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

Names_long <- pivot_longer(Names, -IOCSpecies, values_to = 'binSpecies') %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  bind_rows(data.frame(IOCSpecies = Names$IOCSpecies, binSpecies = Names$IOCSpecies))

left_join(Dataset, Names_long, 'binSpecies')
```

Comment: thank you for the response. This code doubles my dataset: Dataset <- data.frame(
  IndivID <- (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
  binSpecies <- ("Dog", "Dog", "Gato", "Gato", "Canine", "Canine")
  IOCSpecies <- ("Canine", "Canine", "Feline", "Feline", "Canine", "Canine")
  In addition, I get an error message:  Warning message:
In left_join(Dataset, Names_long, "binSpecies") :
  Each row in `x` is expected to match at most 1 row in `y`.
i Row 1 of `x` matches multiple rows.
i If multiple matches are expected, set `multiple = "all"` to silence this warning.

Comment: actually I think I misunderstood your comment, it works now, thanks!